# Bent arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to create a graphical model (a bit like a Bayesian network) in which some of the arrows are bent. I am using the tikz package.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}  
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\tikz{ %
\node[obs] (C) {C} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C] (M1) {M1} ; %
\node[obs, right=of M1] (M2) {M2} ; %
\node[obs, right=of M2] (E) {E} ; %
\node[ellipse, latent, above=1.5] (Mechanism) {Mechanism} ; %
\edge {C} {M1} ; %
\edge {M1} {M2} ; %
\edge {M2} {E} ; %
\edge[dashed, bend right] {Mechanism} {C}
\edge[dashed, bend right] {Mechanism} {M1}
\edge[dashed, bend left] {Mechanism} {M2}
\edge[dashed, bend left] {Mechanism} {E}
 } 
\tikz{ %
\node[obs] (C) {C} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C, yshift=1.25cm] (E1) {E1} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C] (E2) {E2} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C, yshift=-1.25cm] (E3) {E3} ; %
\node[ellipse, latent, above=1.5] (Mechanism) {Mechanism} ; %
\edge {C} {E1} ; %
\edge {C} {E2} ; %
\edge {C} {E3} ; %
\edge[dashed, bend right] {Mechanism} {C} ;%
\edge[dashed, bend left] {Mechanism} {E1} ;%
\edge[dashed, bend right] {Mechanism} {E2} ;%
\edge[dashed, out = 200, in = 270] {Mechanism} {E3} ;
 } 
 \tikz{ %
\node[obs] (E) {E} ; %
\node[obs, left=of E, yshift=1.25cm] (C1) {C1} ; %
\node[obs, left=of E] (C2) {C2} ; %
\node[obs, left=of E, yshift=-1.25cm] (C3) {C3} ; %
\node[ellipse, latent, above=1.5] (Mechanism) {Mechanism} ; %
\edge {C1} {E} ; %
\edge {C2} {E} ; %
\edge {C3} {E} ; %
\edge[dashed, bend right] {Mechanism} {C1} ;%
\edge[dashed, bend left] {Mechanism} {C2} ;%
\edge[dashed, out = 180, in =180] {Mechanism} {C3} ;%
\edge[dashed, bend left] {Mechanism} {E} ;
}
 \caption{blah}
 \label{fig:mechanism}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code had previously generated something that looked like this:

[image: what I want it to look like]

However I recently upgraded to my LaTeX editor (Texpad) and now for some reason the bent dashed edges are straight:

[image: not how I want it to look]

Would anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This almost certainly does not come from your *editor*. You need to provide a full [MWE}(https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for people to help you.

Comment: @marmot is that more helpful now?

Comment: Yes and no. You have provided an MWE that runs through without a problem, which is quite something. However, I reproduce the output of your lower screenshot. And I am wondering about the way you are using `edge`s. It is very reminiscent of the `\Edge` command provided by the `tkz-graph` package, which you load but don't seem to use.

Comment: @marmot thanks for your input, problem solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes frome the syntax :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}  
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\node[obs] (C) {C} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C] (M1) {M1} ; %
\node[obs, right=of M1] (M2) {M2} ; %
\node[obs, right=of M2] (E) {E} ; %
\node[ellipse, latent, above=1.5] (Mechanism) {Mechanism} ; %
\edge {C} {M1} ; %
\edge {M1} {M2} ; %
\edge {M2} {E} ; %

\foreach \x/\y in {C/right,M1/right,M2/left,E/left}
\path (Mechanism) edge [dashed, bend \y,->]  (\x) ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
\node[obs] (C) {C} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C, yshift=1.25cm] (E1) {E1} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C] (E2) {E2} ; %
\node[obs, right=of C, yshift=-1.25cm] (E3) {E3} ; %
\node[ellipse, latent, above=1.5] (Mechanism) {Mechanism} ; %
\edge {C} {E1} ; %
\edge {C} {E2} ; %
\edge {C} {E3} ; %
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, bend right]  (C) ;%
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, bend left] (E1) ;%
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, bend right] (E2) ;%
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, out = 200, in = 270] (E3) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
\node[obs] (E) {E} ; %
\node[obs, left=of E, yshift=1.25cm] (C1) {C1} ; %
\node[obs, left=of E] (C2) {C2} ; %
\node[obs, left=of E, yshift=-1.25cm] (C3) {C3} ; %
\node[ellipse, latent, above=1.5] (Mechanism) {Mechanism} ; %
\edge {C1} {E} ; %
\edge {C2} {E} ; %
\edge {C3} {E} ; %
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, bend right]  (C) ;%
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, bend left] (C2) ;%
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, out = 180, in =180] (C3) ;%
\path (Mechanism) edge[dashed, bend left] (E) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

 \caption{blah}
 \label{fig:mechanism}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you're an absolute hero